# Convert SQL variables in snowflake

Tags: javascript, sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am converting a SQL stored procedure to snowflake , code of which is as follows:

```
Create PROCEDURE <sp_name>  (@parameter)
AS
BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON

Declare 
@A varchar(max), 
@B smallint = 0,
@C int = 0,
        DECLARE @D smallint,
            @E smalldatetime,
            @F smallint
```

Need some help to understand how will I convert the above variables in snowflake to be consumed by sql statement.

Answer (score 0):

I would look into Snowflake Scripting, you can use variables in expressions and SQL statements.  This should have the equivalent functionality you are looking for.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference-snowflake-scripting.html
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/variables.html#examples-of-using-variables

```
create or replace procedure myprocedure()
returns table(A varchar, B smallint, C integer, D smallint, E 
timestamp_ntz, F smallint)
language SQL
as
$$
declare
A varchar default null; 
B smallint default 0;
C integer default 0;
D smallint default -1;
E timestamp_ntz default current_timestamp();
F smallint default 0;
res RESULTSET default (select :A,:B,:C,:D,:E,:F);
begin
  return table(res);
end
$$
;    

call myprocedure();
A   B   C   D   E   F
0   0   -1  2022-02-23 11:53:21.230 0
```

Comment: I won't use language SQL for stored proc, I will be using Javascript for it where return will be varchar `returns varchar not null
    language javascript`